# Node class in a Linked List

Tags: java, dts

```
private E  value;
private Node <E> next; //this one

public Node( E newVal,Node <E> newNext) {

    value = newVal;
    next = newNext; //and this one

}
```

I'm really struggling to understand/visualize how the constructor is referencing the next Node by "`next = newNext`" and why must the variable type  be identical  to the class name.

Comment: `next = newNext` just assigns to the node's `next` pointer whatever was passed into the constructor.  As to why `next` is of type `Node<E>` it should be intuitive: A node points to another node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a group of Letters (A,B,C,D). You want to arrange them as a list. One way to do so is the following: A comes first, and you tell A that letter after it is B (which is a letter). And then you tell B that the letter after it is C, etc. What you're doing here is  *linking*  the letters together.

Applying that concept to your case: Let's say you have a bunch of Nodes. A Node has a value of type E (`E value`), but in order for Nodes to be arranged as a list, you must tell each Node the Node that comes after it.

Hence when constructing a Node, you have to pass in a `E newVal` and a `Node newNext`, but remember in your case Node is parameterized over E. The Node you pass in must then also be parameterized over E, hence you pass in `Node<E> newNext`.